# innerHTML and conditional (ternary) operator- "unexpected string"

Tags: html, css

Can someone please help me? I am trying to enable this program to load a page with all numbers separated by an hr tag, **except** for the last number (#10). Right now there appears to be an "unexpected string" in the code block after my *if* statement.

I've tried several different permutations for that line, but I'm stumped as to how to get this working. Thank you in advance!

```js
var n = 1, str = ""

  while (n <= 10) {
    if (n % 2 === 0) {
      str += "<p class='even'>" + n + (n === 10 ? "" : "<hr>") "</p>"
    } else {
      str += "<p class='odd'>" + n + "</p><hr>"
    }
    n++
  }

  document.querySelector("#target").innerHTML = str
```

```html
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  .even {
    color:blue;
  }
  .odd {
    color:red;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="target"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to change:

```
str += "<p class='even'>" + n + (n === 10 ? "" : "<hr>") "</p>"
```

to:

```
str += "<p class='even'>" + n + (n === 10 ? "" : "<hr>") + "</p>"
```

?